# Saving RDD into files

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to write an RDD of type `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String), Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[21]` into a file:

I created my RDD through this code:

```
val res = motList2.cartesian(motList2).map { case (x, y) =>
((x._1, y._1), x._2 + y._2)
}

val dir = "H:\\procjet-results"
res.saveAsTextFile(dir)
```

motList2 can be something like:

```
motList2=List( (("Chicken","Pasta"),2), ("Chicken","robot"),3) ... )
```

But I always have an exception

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException
```

I checked, the folder is created but all the files are empty.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException", the reason your job fails is that the directory/file where you are trying to write already exists. If you had experience with hadoop before. This is the same problem. Spark by default will not overwrite the location where you are trying to save your results so if it already there you have to delete it first manually or in your code.

Comment: Actually I removed the folder but I still have the same error. Hadoop create a folder with empty files in it. Then launch an exception

Comment: Seems a bit odd. A reason why Spark create empty files could be that there are empty partitions for some keys. Have you tried to see if there is anything in "res" before you write the result to disk. If you use an IDE you can easily run your spark code locally in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the file:// prefix for the url to be on the safer side;a lot many times hdfs is the default where it tries to save the file.